# Significato di "filo" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Le otto montagne*, di Paolo Cognetti, ho letto questo passaggio che fa riferimento a un incidente dell'io narrante mentre fa arrampicata (grassetto mio):

> Poi andai giú. Un volo di una decina di metri non è niente di davvero grave, però bisognerebbe saper cadere: spingersi in fuori dalla parete e attutire il colpo con le gambe alla fine del volo. A me non l’aveva insegnato nessuno e andai giú dritto, scorticandomi sulla roccia nel tentativo di tenermi. Sentii una fitta all’inguine quando arrivai in fondo. Ma quest’altro dolore era una fortuna, voleva dire che qualcuno aveva bloccato la corda. Ora non ridevano piú. 
>          Poco dopo uscimmo in cima alla parete e fu strano, a quel punto, trovarsi di nuovo nei prati. Con un **filo** tirato a un passo dal precipizio, le mucche al pascolo, un alpeggio mezzo diroccato, un cane che abbaiava.

Non capisco bene cosa sia questo "filo" che appare nell'ultima frase di questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo "filo" in alcuni dizionari, ma ce ne sono tante accezioni... Si riferisce forse alla corda usata per l'arrampicata? Mi sembra piuttosto strambo che una corda venga chiamata "filo".

Comment: Un filo è sottile, precario, e indica, anche in senso figurato, la poca distanza da qualche cosa. Sembra che il narratore arriva a un pascolo, affacciato sul precipizio, e perciò delimitato da un filo. La descrizione, con la scelta e la vicinanza delle parole ("un filo", "a un passo", "precipizio"), e la costruzione della frase fanno percepire lo spavento e la sensazione di pericolo, ancora vivo nella mente.

Comment: Però nel brano si fa riferimento  al dolore all'inguine per una corda bloccata.  
Il filo tirato potrebbe essere meno figurativo e più reale, come essere appesi 
alla corda, ad un passo dal precipizio. 
L'utilizzo della parola filo magari è relativo alla precarietà (essere appesi a un filo dà più l'idea di pericolo che essere attaccati alla corda).

Comment: @OldManofAran: Potresti scrivere quello che hai detto nel tuo comento come risposta?

Comment: @OldManofAran: mi sembra del tutto ragionevole che "filo" sia [questo](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fc8.alamy.com%2Fcompit%2Ffgpj3n%2Fun-vuoto-campo-di-pascolo-con-del-filo-spinato-fgpj3n.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.it%2Ffoto-immagine-un-vuoto-campo-di-pascolo-con-del-filo-spinato-96383497.html&docid=xbeJE2UxgJGoBM&tbnid=x9OS8v7zh5gtSM%3A&vet=1&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim).

Comment: "aver tirato un filo" secondo me significa in questo contesto aver scampato per un pelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il paesaggio che i protagonisti dell'arrampicata si trovano davanti è strano, per loro stessa ammissione.

Infatti è un normale pascolo alpino, inaspettato dopo la difficile e pericolosa ascesa: un prato con un filo tirato perché le vacche non si avvicinassero troppo al precipizio.

Se una vacca non è spaventata (e non succede spesso), non tenta mai di forzare passaggi dove trova un ostacolo, quindi un filo (robusto) è più che sufficiente per tenerla a bada.

L'autore adopera *filo* per contrasto con la *corda* dell'arrampicata: sempre corde sono, ma il filo per delimitare il precipizio è più sottile o, almeno, così appare al narratore.

Answer (score 0):

Si, è strano che una corda venga chiamata filo. Di solito una corda è robusta, mentre un filo è sottile. 
Senza ulteriore contesto né sapere cosa dica prima o dopo il libro, io direi che fa riferimento alla corda che è stata bloccata mentre lui stava cadendo, salvandolo.

Un filo a volte (anche se viene usato raramente) è una metafora per indicare qualcosa che si evita per poco, al pari di *perdere il treno per un pelo*. L'autore è stato salvato da un *filo* che, in realtà, era una corda. Ma in questo processo si è sentito molto vicino allo sfracellarsi, quindi chiamando la corda filo sottolinea che ci è mancato poco.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @MarMik, e grazie della risposta. Se n'era parlato nei commenti (qualcuno è sparito) e, personalmente, adesso mi sembra più plausibile che "filo" sia [questo](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fc8.alamy.com%2Fcompit%2Ffgpj3n%2Fun-vuoto-campo-di-pascolo-con-del-filo-spinato-fgpj3n.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.it%2Ffoto-immagine-un-vuoto-campo-di-pascolo-con-del-filo-spinato-96383497.html&docid=xbeJE2UxgJGoBM&tbnid=x9OS8v7zh5gtSM%3A&vet=1&source=sh%2Fx%2Fim).